# Automating Choropleth map creation from table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, maps, choropleth

I am trying to create soil nutrient maps from an excel table. My table has the location with multiple nutrients for each location (Nitrogen, Potassium, pH etc). I would like to create a choropleth map for each nutrient, i.e: a map showing the Nitrogen levels at each location, a map showing Potassium levels at each location.

I currently can struggle through it and make each map separately but this takes forever! Is there a way to automate this process in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to do Basic Vector Styling for which there is a [tutorial available](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html) with the same name.

I don't know what you mean by doing it separately.